# YouTube search url for searching username and keywords; and sort results by rating

Tags: search, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a script that will display the json results of a youtube search. The following url will not sort though it does return the results provided I put in a username into *username*.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/username/uploads?alt=json-in-script&search_sort=video_view_count
```

This doesn't seem to sort. And also it doesn't seem to be able to search by keywords if I append `&q=dogs`

Is it possible to search for username plus keywords and sort it afterwards?

Comment: I found this gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=username&alt=json-in-script. But if I add q= it no longer searches. Is there something about json-in-script that prevents using q=?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the URL you need:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos
?v=2
&author=SesameStreet
&q=rubber+ducky
&orderby=viewCount
&start-index=1
&max-results=10
&alt=json-in-script
&callback=myCallbackFunction
&prettyprint=true
```

[Click here to view the output](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&author=SesameStreet&q=rubber+ducky&orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=10&alt=json-in-script&callback=myCallbackFunction&prettyprint=true)

Parameters used:

> **author** In a search request, the author parameter restricts the search to videos uploaded by a particular YouTube user.
>
> **q** The q parameter specifies a search query term.
>
> **orderby** The orderby parameter, which is supported for video feeds and playlist feeds, specifies the method that will be used to order
>   entries in the API response.

The [complete documentation is available here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference), you should refer it for additional parameters, possible values and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using q=something
I used search_query=something
q apparently searches for the exact match